# Is there any way to render rooms with captured images using RoomPlan?

Tags: 3d, scenekit, arkit, lidar, roomplan

I am now building an interior configurator using RoomPlan API.

The app's workflow will be the following:

1. Scan the room with RoomPlan and get the geometry of the room
2. Render the room with captured images obtained while scanning the room. This will be the surfaces of the room
3. Users can see the digital twin of the room

In this flow, I have trouble completing step 2. The default implementation of the RoomPlan API seems that it does not have the feature of configuring scanned rooms with captured images.
Are there any ways to complete this task using RoomPlan API or other APIs?